# Disable pop-up calendar when clicking date picker in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing program on javafx and i use datepicker. I want to disable pop-up calendar when i click the calendar image. Dont advice that just use textfield instead of datepicker and parse it

Comment: Button btn = new Button();
 btn.setMinSize(50, 100);
 btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
   LocalDate date2 = dP2.getValue();
            dayLabel2.setText(" "+date2.getDayOfMonth());
            monthLabel2.setText(" "+date2.getMonthValue());
            yearLabel2.setText(" "+date2.getYear());
   
  }
 }); 
In generally, i want to let the user enter date use keyboard(not using calender which pops up when u click the calendar image) . when pressing button i want to get values written in datepicker text area.

Comment: You could edit your post instead of writing so much code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason behind of not using a textfield?? Is it a strict requirement, if no you can simply add a textfield ontop of the datePicker textfield. And declare a arraylist to store the date entered by the user from the textfield. If the user choose a specific date from the datePicker and that date fit into one of the date in your arraylist (to see whether fit simply loop through all the content in the string arraylist and do .equal comparison) then display it on the label. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
         String pattern = "yyyy-dd-MM";
         ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
         Pane pane = new Pane();
         TextField tf = new TextField();
         Label lb = new Label();
         DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();

         tf.setPromptText(pattern);
         lb.setLayoutX(200);
         lb.setLayoutY(250);

         lb.setText("To know where the label is");

         Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);


         pane.getChildren().addAll(datePicker,tf,lb);

         primaryStage.show();

         datePicker.setOnAction(event -> {
                for(int x=0;x<al.size();x++)
                {
                     System.out.println(al.get(x));
                     System.out.println(datePicker.getValue().toString());

                    if(datePicker.getValue().toString().equals( al.get(x).toString()))
                    {
                        lb.setText("is a checked date");
                    }
                }

            });
         tf.setOnAction(event -> {
             al.add(tf.getText());
             System.out.println(al.get(0).toString());
         });

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datePicker.setEditable(false);

datePicker.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
     if(!datePicker.isEditable())
         datePicker.hide();
});
```